# Improve performance of a JavaScript function (with an array lookup)

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm trying to complete a code challenge where I have to decode the keystrokes of a cell phone t9 input into characters to create a text message. The main function (reverse_t9) takes a string of keys such as "44 444" or "999337777" and I need to translate them to their corresponding texts ("hi", or "yes" respectively).

I have all the logic down and can generate the correct outputs, but the challenge is telling me that I'm exceeding the time limit which is 4000ms. I've found a couple spots to improve performance, but still can't get it under that mark. I think the biggest time-waster is my "getLetterFromDigits" function which has to iterate through my array to find the corresponding mapping for a set of keystrokes.

Am I missing some other obvious performance problems? Please let me know if you need more info.

```
function reverse_t9(keys) {
    var retVal = "";
    var maxKeystrokes = 3;
    var splitKeystrokes = splitKeystrokesBySpacesAndKeys(keys);

    for (i = 0, numSplits = splitKeystrokes.length; i < numSplits; i++){
        //console.log("THIS SPLIT:");
        //console.log(splitKeystrokes[i]);
        //console.log("THIS LETTER:");
        //console.log(getLetterFromDigits(splitKeystrokes[i]));
        retVal = retVal + getLetterFromDigits(splitKeystrokes[i]);
    }

    return retVal;
}

function splitKeystrokesBySpacesAndKeys(keys) {
    var retVal = [];
    var lastKey = "";
    var thisKey = "";
    var lastSplit = 0;
    var isSpace = 0;

    for (i = 0, numKeys = keys.length; i <= numKeys; i++) {

        thisKey = keys.substring(i, i + 1);

        if (i == 0) {
            // FIRST TIME AROUND, DO NOTHING ELSE, JUST ASSIGN LAST KEY
            lastKey = thisKey;
        } else {
            if (thisKey != lastKey) {
                if (thisKey != " ") {
                    if (lastKey != " ") {
                        retVal.push(keys.substring(lastSplit, i));
                    } else {
                        retVal.push(keys.substring(lastSplit, i - 1));
                    }

                    lastSplit = i;
                }

                lastKey = thisKey;

            } else {
                // KEY DID NOT CHANGE, ASSIGN LAST KEY AND CONTINUE ON
                lastKey = thisKey;
            }
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}

function getLetterFromDigits(digits){
    var retVal;

    var digitMapping = [
    {
        digit: "1",
        mapping: []
    },
    {
        digit: "2",
        mapping: ["a", "b", "c"]
    },
    {
        digit: "3",
        mapping: ["d", "e", "f"]
    },
    {
        digit: "4",
        mapping: ["g", "h", "i"]
    },
    {
        digit: "5",
        mapping: ["j", "k", "l"]
    },
    {
        digit: "6",
        mapping: ["m", "n", "o"]
    },
    {
        digit: "7",
        mapping: ["p", "q", "r", "s"]
    },
    {
        digit: "8",
        mapping: ["t", "u", "v"]
    },
    {
        digit: "9",
        mapping: ["w", "x", "y", "z"]
    },
    {
        digit: "0",
        mapping: ["*"]
    }

    ];

    var digit = digits.substring(0, 1);


    for (i = 0, numMappings = digitMapping.length; i < numMappings; i++){
        if (digitMapping[i].digit == digit){
            retVal = digitMapping[i].mapping[digits.length - 1];
            break;
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Probably better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For one thing, instead of setting up that key to mapping list like that, you could make a simple array. You're mapping strings "0" through "9" - that's a simple array lookup. Just make an array of arrays.

Comment: Also, instead of `keys.substring(i, i+1)` you can see if `keys.charAt(i)` or simply `keys[i]` is faster.

Comment: Whoops... Didn't know about codereview. And @Pointy you mean like:

var digitMapping = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']...]; ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for code review.

Comment: FYI, nowhere are you using JSON. JSON is a *textual* data-exchange format.

Comment: What's the difference between asking about a performance issue and asking for a code review? I don't think I'm asking for a code review here, I'm asking a specific question based on specific parameters, right?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the JSON. I guess what I meant is I'm just using a generic JS object in this instance.

Comment: The biggest problem I can spot is that you've forgotten to declare the `i` variable as local with `var` in all of your three loops. This is likely the reason for the abysimal runtime, though you must have been lucky to still see it a) terminate and b) get the correct results.

Comment: Whoa I didn't even notice that. I have no idea how that was working.

Comment: Oh no, I see. Without declaring "var", JS looked up until it hit the global scope, then instantiated the variable. Each time I used it from there, it did the same until it found that already-declared one, but still reset it to 0 because each loop had that assignment in there. But you're right, trying to find that variable probably slowed it down. Good catch @Bergi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, declare your digit mapping outside of the function, so you're reusing the results of that work rather than performing that work every time the function is called.

Secondly, make `digitMapping` use key/value pairs so you can do a quick lookup based on a given property name rather than having to loop through it.

```
var digitMapping = 
{
    "1": [],
    "2": ["a", "b", "c"],
    ...
};

function getLetterFromDigits(digits){
    var digit = digits.substring(0, 1);
    return digitMapping[digit][digits.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution - Let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: @xboxremote: It wasn't correct at first (still might not be) but hopefully it'll give you the right idea.

Comment: I think it does... Still working through it, but I gotcha.

Comment: This did the trick. I had to add the "space bar" character mapped for 0 in order to get it to work, and I ended up doing away with the key/value pairs, and just did an array of arrays:

`var digitMapping = [
    [" "],
    [],
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["d", "e", "f"],
    ["g", "h", "i"],
    ["j", "k", "l"],
    ["m", "n", "o"],
    ["p", "q", "r", "s"],
    ["t", "u", "v"],
    ["w", "x", "y", "z"]
];`

Answer (score 1):

Few pointers:

1. Save length in a variable and use it. Using `Array.length` will check for every iteration.
2. Instead of having array of objects, create 1 mapping object like:

```js
{
  "1": [],
  "2": ["a", "b", "c"]
},
```

and fetch it as `digitMapping[mapping[digits.length - 1]]`

3. Instead of `thisKey = keys.substring(i, i + 1);`, you can save characters in a variable like `char_arr = keys.split("")` and loop over it.
4. You can get rid of 1 iteration(first iteration). Just set `lastKey = char_arr[0]` or `lastKey=keys.charAt(0)`
5. Else part for `if (thisKey != lastKey)` is not required. If both values are same, you do not need to set `lastKey = thisKey;`

Answer (score 0):

Try my version.

```
function getMsg(val){
  //split digits to array
  val = val.split('');
  //some internal vars
  var letter = [];
  var last = val[0];
  var msg='';
  for(var i=0,n=val.length;i<n;i++){
    if(val[i]==last)
      //collect sequential digits
      letter.push(val[i]);
    else{
      //new digit 
      msg += digMap[letter[0]][letter.length-1];
      //reinit letter array
      letter=[val[i]];
      last = val[i];
    }
  }
  msg += digMap[letter[0]][letter.length-1];
  return msg; //return decoded
}
//map digits as @Rajesh recommended
var digMap={
  "1":[" "],
  "2":'abc'.split(''),
  "3":'def'.split(''),
  "4":'ghi'.split(''),
  "5":'jkl'.split(''),
  "6":'mno'.split(''),
  "7":'pqrs'.split(''),
  "8":'tuv'.split(''),
  "9":'wxyz'.split(''),
  "0":["*"],
  " ":['']
}
//test functionality
console.time('txt');
console.log(getMsg('999337777'));
//yes
console.timeEnd('txt');
```